# Dar Hide em um ActionLink, é possivel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Gostaria de dependendo da condição meu `ActionLink` ficasse visível ou não.

**Razor**:

```
<td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Cadastrar site","MontarFancyCadastrarSite", "ItemOS", 
       new {ChaveOS = Model.ChaveOS }, new { @class = "siteFancybox fancybox.iframe" })
</td>
```

**JQuery**:

```
$("#ChaveSite").change(function () {
   $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CarregarContatoSite","OS")',{chaveSite: $('#ChaveSite').val()}, 
     function (contatos) {
        if (contatos.length > 0)
        {
            $(this).parent().find("a.siteFancybox fancybox.iframe").show();
        } else {                              
            $(this).parent().find("a.siteFancybox fancybox.iframe").hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Dessa forma acima não está funcionando, alguém poderia me mostrar o erro ou outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver assim:

Primeiro, setei o Id no elemento no

**RAZOR:**

```
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Cadastrar site","MontarFancyCadastrarSite", "ItemOS", 
                new {ChaveOS = Model.ChaveOS }, new { @class = "siteFancybox fancybox.iframe", id="cadastrarSite" })
            </td>
```

E no **JQuery:**

```
  $("#ChaveSite").change(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CarregarContatoSite", "OS")', { chaveSite: $('#ChaveSite').val() }, function (contatos) {
        if (contatos.length > 0) {               
             $("#cadastrarSite").show();
        } else {                              
            $("#cadastrarSite").hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Funcionou perfeitamente para o meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

No lugar disso:

```
$(this).parent().find("a.siteFancybox fancybox.iframe").show();
```

coloque isso:

```
$('a.siteFancybox').parent().show();
```

eu acredito que ele não esteja encontrando o item correto inclusive porque na sua pergunta você não especificou aonde estava `#ChaveSite`

***Um exemplo simples:***

```js
var contatos = 1;
$("#select").on("change", function()
{
  contatos = (contatos == 1) ? 0 : 1;
  if (contatos == 1) {
    $("a.siteFancybox").parent().show();
  } else {
    $("a.siteFancybox").parent().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <select id="select">
    <option value="1">Aparecer</option>
    <option value="0">Desaparecer</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.uol.com.br" 
         class="siteFancybox fancybox.iframe">Uol</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: o #ChaveSite é um DDL.